# OpenCV vector of vectors into cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, mat

I have certain values in an `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`structure of n rows and m cols which I would like to convert into an equivalent cv::Mat object. This is the code I have been using but I'm getting an error:

dctm is a local argument which is defined as:
`std::vector<std::vector<double>>`

```
cv::Mat dctmat = cvCreateMat(dctm.size(), dctm[0].size(), CV_16SC1);
for (size_t i = 0; i < dctm.size(); i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < dctm[i].size(); j++) {
        dctmat.at<double>(i, j) = dctm[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you get ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dctmat` has  a type `CV_16SC1` which means matrix of signed short. But you try to access it with `dctmat.at<double>(i, j)` which is incoherent. Either define your matrix as `CV_64FC1` or access it with `dctmat.at<short>(i, j)` (first solution is better because you have a vector of `double`).

Answer (score 3):

Here is my templated version of conversion routines

routines

```
template<typename _Tp> static  cv::Mat toMat(const vector<vector<_Tp> > vecIn) {
    cv::Mat_<_Tp> matOut(vecIn.size(), vecIn.at(0).size());
    for (int i = 0; i < matOut.rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matOut.cols; ++j) {
            matOut(i, j) = vecIn.at(i).at(j);
        }
    }
    return matOut;
}
template<typename _Tp> static  vector<vector<_Tp> > toVec(const cv::Mat_<_Tp> matIn) {
    vector<vector<_Tp> > vecOut(matIn.rows);
    for (int i = 0; i < matIn.rows; ++i) {
        vecOut[i].resize(matIn.cols);
        for (int j = 0; j < matIn.cols; ++j) {
            vecOut[i][j] =  matIn.at<_Tp>(i, j);
        }
    }
    return vecOut;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

[Here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat) in the Opencv documentation you can found this:

```
Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, void* data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)
Mat::Mat(Size size, int type, void* data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)
...
```

then, you can use like this:

```
Mat dctmat(dctm.size(), dctm[0].size(), CV_16SC1, dctm.data());
```

Comment: did you try it? that `dctm.data()` doesn't work for me as a *vector of vector*